# How to use the setTimeout with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the code:

```
if (xxx == xxx){
    var x = 5 + 3;
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.regErrMsg').text("");
        $scope.errMsg = "Hi.";
    }, 5000);
}
```

I would like to execute the function i.e, show "Hi" message after 5 seconds.  So, is my code correct.  As of now, the message is not showing up. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The setTimeout looks fine... are you seeing `.regErrMsg` text go away? What do you expect changing the .errMsg property of $scope to do? It doesn't seem like something that would pop up a message right away? Perhaps you should put a console.log before the setTimeout and inside the setTimeout callback and watch your console. This will help you determine where exactly the problem is.

Comment: Is whatever this condition is `if (xxx == xxx){` being met cos it looks a little dodgy? Is it real code?

Comment: yes.... xxx - I replaced my condition.. just take that as a true value.

Comment: Have you checked the console for error messages?

Comment: `$scope.errMsg = "Hi.";` IS just setting a string, You need to do something else that triggers the code that upates the DOM. With the limited code, your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: $('.regErrMsg').text(""): I wanted to to clear the value of a span that has the class .regErrMsg.

Comment: @JayarajPS, and you are not seeing that span get cleared?

Comment: My question is .. does the Hi executes and then it waits for 5 sec or wait waits for 5 secs and then shows Hi ?

Comment: It should wait 5 seconds before running the callback (which contains the "Hi" code.

Comment: Paul S : I am using Angular, hence $scope ...

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: `$scope.errMsg = "Hi."; $scope.$apply()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is .. does the Hi executes and then it waits for 5 sec or wait waits for 5 secs and then shows Hi ?

Let's consider a simplified example

```
foo();
setTimeout(function () {bar();}, 5000);
baz();
```

Now it's easier to describe what will happen, step by step (in excruciating detail)

1. ***Line 1:*** `foo` gets interpreted
2. `()` invokes `foo`
3. ***Line 2:*** `setTimeout` gets interpreted
4. The arguments to be passed into `setTimeout` are interpreted, i.e. function references set here
5. The `(/* ... */)` invokes `setTimeout`
6. `setTimeout` sets up a callback to invoke *argument `0`* after *argument `1`* milliseconds
7. ***Line 3:*** `baz` gets interpreted
8. `()` invokes baz
9. ***End of file*** *...nothing happens for a while...*
10. *argument `0`* (from `5`) gets invoked
11. `bar` gets interpreted (using references from `4`)
12. `()` invokes `bar`

---

> As of now, the message is not showing up. Where have I gone wrong?

It looks like the only change you've made that will be reflected in the *DOM* is the clearing of text from `.regErrMsg`, perhaps you meant to use

```
$('.regErrMsg').text("Hi.");
```

or invoke some other method which will make the updated vale of `$scope` be reflected in the *#document*

Answer (score 3):

The "problem" with setTimeout inside your controller is that angular is not going to watch the content of the scope after the function in the setTimeout is called.

## Solution 1

You can do `$scope.$apply()` to force the view to update, eg:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    $scope.errMsg = "Hi.";
    $scope.$apply();
}, 5000);
```

## Solution 2

They is a special function `$timeout` which will trigger the view refresh automatically after the function has been called. It has the same signature as setTimeout.

```
$timeout(function() { 
    $scope.errMsg = "Hi.";
    //You don't need $scope.$apply() here
}, 5000);
```

You should inject $timeout into your controller

I have removed the `$('.regErrMsg').text("");` because you shouldn't change the dom inside a controller.